# Does OS X have an equivalent to /dev/shm?

Tags: linux, macos, ipc, ramdisk

Does OS X (Snow Leopard in particular) have an equivalent to (some versions of) Linux's `/dev/shm` , ie something where you can write to and read from a file without necessarily touching the hard drive?

Answer (score 61):

You can create and mount a ram based disk as follows:

1. Create a disk

   ```
   hdiutil attach -nomount ram://$((2 * 1024 * SIZE_IN_MB))
   ```

   `hdiutil` will return the name of the ramdisk.
2. Format and mount the disk

   ```
   diskutil eraseVolume HFS+ RAMDisk NAME_OF_DISK
   ```
3. Access the disk under `/Volumes/<diskname>`

   ```
   cd /Volumes/RAMDisk && touch testfile.txt && ls
   ```

Creating a 100MB ramdisk:

```
$ hdiutil attach -nomount ram://$((2 * 1024 * 100))
/dev/disk3

$ diskutil eraseVolume HFS+ RAMDisk /dev/disk3
Started erase on disk3
Unmounting disk
Erasing
Initialized /dev/rdisk3 as a 100 MB case-insensitive HFS Plus volume
Mounting disk
Finished erase on disk3 RAMDisk
```

*Original source: http://www.frederico-araujo.com/2008/12/18/blazing-fast-firefox-using-osx-ramdisk/* ([archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20100209054854/http://www.frederico-araujo.com/2008/12/18/blazing-fast-firefox-using-osx-ramdisk/))

Comment: Broken links are one of the reasons why the StackOverflow community prefer full answers over links without any explanation.

Comment: @Nupraptor: I updated the answer with a real answer. Thanks for bringing it to my attention!

Comment: broken link, but found archived here: https://web.archive.org/web/20100209054854/http://www.frederico-araujo.com/2008/12/18/blazing-fast-firefox-using-osx-ramdisk/