# Named memory-mapped files in Python?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm using [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/) to process some video data in a web service. Before calling OpenCV, the video is already loaded to a `bytearray` buffer, which I would like to pass to `VideoCapture` object:

```
# The following raises cv2.error because it can't convert '_io.BytesIO' to 'str' for 'filename'
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(buffer)
```

Unfortunately, `VideoCapture()` expects a string filename, not a buffer. For now, I'm saving the `bytearray` to a temporary file, and pass its name to `VideoCapture()`.

Questions:

- Is there a way to create *named* in-memory files in Python, so I can pacify OpenCV?
- Alternatively, is there another OpenCV API which does support buffers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: POSIX-specific! As you haven't provided OS tag, I assume it's okay.

According to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26366/296803) (and [this `shm_overview` manpage](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html)) there is `/dev/shm` always present on the system. That's a `tmpfs` mapped in a **shared** (not Python process memory) memory pool, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69328165/5994041), but the plus is that you *don't* need to create it, so no funny inventing of:

- `os.system("mount ...")` or
- `Popen(["mount", ...])` wrappers.

Simply use [`tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile) like this:

```py
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
with NamedTemporaryFile(dir="/dev/shm") as file:
    print(file.name)
    # /dev/shm/tmp2m86e0e0
```

which you could then feed into OpenCV's API wrapper. Alternatively, utilize [`pyfilesystem`](https://pyfilesystem.readthedocs.io) as a more extensive wrapper around that device/FS.

Also, [`multiprocessing.heap.Arena`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7834ff26cbcd4d8394d64d80d9f51a364d38b1c6/Lib/multiprocessing/heap.py#L73) uses it too, so if it didn't work, there'd be much more trouble present. For Windows [check this implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7834ff26cbcd4d8394d64d80d9f51a364d38b1c6/Lib/multiprocessing/heap.py#L31) which uses `winapi`.

For the size of `/dev/shm`:

- [this](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/dev-shm-883346/#post4370388) is one of the size "specifications" I found,
- [`shm.h`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/5bfc75d92efd494db37f5c4c173d3639d4772966/include/uapi/linux/shm.h#L21), [`shm_add_rss_swap()`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/7cca308cfdc0725363ac5943dca9dcd49cc1d2d5/ipc/shm.c#L831), [`newseg()`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/7cca308cfdc0725363ac5943dca9dcd49cc1d2d5/ipc/shm.c#L600) from Linux source code may hold more details

Judging by [`sudo ipcs`](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/dev-shm-883346/page2.html#post4372982) it's most likely **the** way you want to utilize when sharing stuff between processes if you don't use sockets, pipes or disk.

As it's POSIX, it should work on POSIX-compliant systems, thus <s>also on MacOS</s>([no](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2033362/5994041)) or Solaris, but I have no means to try it.

Comment: Using `/dev/shm` is a good idea.  I didn't propose it only because you don't (afaik) get to say how big it is, which *might* be important.  I'd rather make a tmpfs myself and *know* I won't kill the system.  but YMMV

Comment: @2e0byo fair point. I'll try to dig out some constant or setup from the kernel source code and edit the answer, if I find it. For now I've added only linuxquestions.org reference.

Comment: interestingly the output of `cat /proc/mounts | grep tmpfs` on my system suggests `/dev/shm` is not limited by a mount option (but might easily be limited by something else) whilst /tmp is, and /run/user/1000 is even *more* limited: `tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,inode64 0 0
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,nr_inodes=409600,inode64 0 0
tmpfs /run/user/1000 tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=376112k,nr_inodes=94028,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000,inode64 0 0`

Comment: shm.h seems to contain max size constants, so I think it *is* limited

Comment: @2e0byo I'd say it has to be. There isn't anything such as unlimited ram/storage anywhere, otherwise the kernel itself would just hang due to no memory if I just `cat /dev/urandom > /dev/shm/stuff` or similar shooting oneself to the foot. Though most likely it's either distro/family-specific or just limited from the code itself while having left "unlimited" area from the tmpfs mounting. Or maybe it starts with one big memory pool somewhere in the kernel for all tmpfs instances and then just allocated a part of that for each instance, such as `/dev/shm`, `/tmp` etc.

Answer (score 2):

Partially to answer the question: there is no way I know of in *python* to create named file-like objects which point to memory: that's something for an operating system to do.  There is a very easy way to do something very *like* creating named memory mapped files in most modern *nixs: save the file to `/tmp`.  These days `/tmp` is almost always a ramdisk.  But of course it might be zram (basically a compressed ramdisk) and you likely want to check that first.  At any rate it's better than thrashing your disk or depending on os caching.

Incidentally making a dedicated ramdisk is as easy as `mount -t tmpfs -o size=1G tmpfs /path/to/tmpfs` or similarly with `ramfs`.

Looking into it I don't think you're going to have much luck with alternative apis either: the use of filenames goes right down to `cap.cpp`, where we have things like:

```cpp
VideoCapture::VideoCapture(const String& filename, int apiPreference) : throwOnFail(false)
{
    CV_TRACE_FUNCTION();
    open(filename, apiPreference);
}
```

It seems the python bindings are just a thin layer on top of this.  But I'm willing to be proven wrong!

### References

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/videoio/src/cap.cpp#L72

Answer (score 2):

If VideoCapture *was* a regular Python object, *and* it accepted "file-like objects" in addition to paths, you *could* feed it a "file-like object", and it could read from that.

Python's StringIO and BytesIO are file-like objects in memory. Something useful to remember ;)

OpenCV specifically expects a file system path there, so that's **out of the question**.

OpenCV is a library for computer vision. It's not a library for handling video files.

You should look into **[PyAV](https://github.com/PyAV-Org/PyAV)**. It's a (proper!) wrapper for ffmpeg's libraries. You can feed data directly in there and it will decode. [Here are some examples](https://pyav.org/docs/stable/cookbook/basics.html) and [here are its tests that demonstrate further functionality](https://github.com/PyAV-Org/PyAV/tree/main/tests). Its documentation is thin because most usage is (or should have been...) documented by ffmpeg itself.

Comment: Thanks  for suggesting PyAV. I'm using OpenCV, as we'll probably need vision down the road.

Answer (score 1):

You *might* be able to get away with a named pipe. You can use [`os.mkfifo`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.mkfifo) to create one, then use the `multiprocess` module to spawn a background process that feeds the video file into it. Note that `mkfifo` is not supported on Windows.

The most important limitation is that a pipe does not support seeking, so your video won't be seekable or rewindable either. And whether it actually works might depend on the video format and on the backend (gstreamer, v4l2, ...) that OpenCV is using.

Comment: From the file object/filesystem point of view it seems like a broken bike. Then again, if only a simple read-once buffer is necessary, that's pretty much a purpose (one of, at least) of a pipe. +1, I'll for sure use it in the future even this way. Socket-like behavior, kind of.

Comment: Indeed. As for the "broken bike" metaphor: in Unix, not everything on the filesystem has to be a "regular file". For example, `/dev/stdin` and `/dev/stdout` are also streams, and so are most device nodes that communicate with hardware. But sure enough, some libraries _will_ assume that the file you pass to it is seekable.

Comment: Yes, that's why the metaphor. It's a really good way for a quick buffer between any two ends of software, but other than that it's not really useful (in comparison with in-memory file or shared memory). It's probably the cheapest OS-specific form though thus it might be even more preferred than `/dev/shm` in some cases. So like a bike without brakes or without a chain, you *still* can slide on it down the hill and it'll work just fine. Just not the rest of the stuff. :D